# I'm getting "Invalid Initializer", what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main(void) {
    char testStr[50] = "Hello, world!";
    char revS[50] = testStr;
}
```

I get error: "invalid initializer" on the line with `revS`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't initialise `revS` in that manner, you need a very specific thing to the right of the `=`. From `C11 6.7.9 Initialization /14, /16`:

> 14/ An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
>
> Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.
>
> `: : :`
>
> 16/ Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace-enclosed list of initializers for the elements or named members.

---

To achieve the same result, you could replace your code with:

```c
int main (void) {
    char testStr[50] = "Hello, world!";
    char revS[50]; strcpy (revS, testStr);
    // more code here
}
```

That's not technically *initialisation* but achieves the same functional result. If you really *want* initialisation, you can use something like:

```c
#define HWSTR "Hello, world!"
int main (void) {
    char testStr[50] = HWSTR;
    char revS[50] = HWSTR;
    // more code here
}
```

Comment: What's the meaning of ":" you put in the main function?

Comment: @Aaron, it was just to indicate more code but, given how many people ask me that question, I've modified how I do it :-)

Comment: *"need a constant expression on the right of the ="* Is a bit misleading. You either need a string literal (which is a very specific kind of a constant expression), or a brace-enclosed list, elements of which don't have to be const (but the list is not an expression).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: good point, have adjusted, and referenced back to the standard to ensure accuracy.

Answer (score 9):

Arrays arent assignable.

You should use memcpy to copy contents from `testStr` to `revS`

```
memcpy(revS,testStr,50);
```

Answer (score 5):

Only constant expressions can be used to initialize arrays, as in your initialization of `testStr`.

You're trying to initialize `revS` with another array variable, which is **not** a constant expression. If you want to copy the contents of the first string into the second, you'll need to use `strcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

An initializer for a `char[]` needs to be either a literal string or something like `{1,2,3,4}`. It isn't allowed to be the name of another variable.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you plan on manipulating the second array you can also use a pointer:

```
int main(void){
    char textStr[50] = "hello worlds!";
    char *revS = textStr;
    printf("%s\n", revS);
```

}

If you want to get really crazy you can point to a specific location in the array with the reference operator:

```
int main(void){
    char textStr[50] = "hello worlds!";
    char *revS = textStr+5; // or &textStr[5]
    printf("%s\n", revS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
char revS[50] = testStr;
```

which is wrong since you cannot assign `char *` to `char`.

Try `revS = testStr;` it should work.